# MS Project jumbled up

Tags: ms-project

Not sure how, but an MS Project individual ID line data (not Unique ID) has jumbled itself up.
Not sure how it happened, need to reorder the Id back to the sequentional numbering system.

Any thoughts

[Jumbled up IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azhih.png)

Answer (score 0):

The tasks have be sorted by a field other than the ID. To change this back, look for the Sort option on the View tab and select "by ID".

See [Sort tasks, resources, or dates in Project desktop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-tasks-resources-or-dates-in-project-desktop-fe5e7515-0cb3-4427-9be2-ae76aec8ec63) for more information.